# Inline-block display of divs with position relative

Tags: css

I have a series of images each with his own overlay. How can I have them aligned like inline-blocks? I tried adding adding `display: inline-block;`to `.image-wrapper` but the images are always all positioned in the top left corner of the `div.container` (Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/klode/uhowp621/#base)).

Here are the html and css

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}
.image-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.tweetty {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: auto;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.image-vest {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #00f;
  width: 220px;
  height: 300px;
  opacity: 0.4;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <div class="tweetty">
      <img src="http://www.picgifs.com/clip-art/cartoons/tweety/clip-art-tweety-191375.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="image-vest">Tweetty-one</div>
  </div>

  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <div class="tweetty">
      <img src="http://www.picgifs.com/clip-art/cartoons/tweety/clip-art-tweety-191375.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="image-vest">Tweetty-two</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

EDIT:

revised css with dfsq suggestion to remove `position:absolute;` from `.tweetty`.

Quoting dfsq comment:
"Elements with position absolute don't contribute to the width and height of their parent container. So the image-wrapper divs just collapse as if they were empty if all children have `position:absolute;` "

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}
.image-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.tweetty {
  overflow: auto;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.image-vest {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #00f;
  width: 220px;
  height: 300px;
  opacity: 0.4;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <div class="tweetty">
      <img src="http://www.picgifs.com/clip-art/cartoons/tweety/clip-art-tweety-191375.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="image-vest">Tweetty-one</div>
  </div>

  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <div class="tweetty">
      <img src="http://www.picgifs.com/clip-art/cartoons/tweety/clip-art-tweety-191375.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="image-vest">Tweetty-two</div>
  </div>
  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <div class="tweetty">
      <img src="http://www.picgifs.com/clip-art/cartoons/tweety/clip-art-tweety-191375.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="image-vest">Tweetty-three</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Remove `position: absolute` from `.tweetty`.

Comment: @dfsq Thanks this is the solution. My understanding was that every `position: relative` child would be positioned inside the `position:absolute` parent according to  `top` and `left` coordinates. Apparently this is true for the vest but not for tweetty. What am I missing?

Comment: @dfsq Nice concise answer! What is the reason that it works? Thanks.

Comment: Element with position absolute doesn't contribute to parent container width and height. So image-wrapper just collapse as if they were empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fiddled with the fiddle, and this seems to work. removed all the positioning from all but the vest. Used the inline-block display mode. Set top to -300px, and also the bottom-margin, otherwise you get a gap below the images.

```css
.container {
/*    position:relative;*/
}
.image-wrapper {
/*    position: relative;*/
    display: inline-block;
}
.tweetty {
/*    position:absolute;
    overflow:auto;
    top:0;
    left:0;*/
}
.image-vest {
    position:relative;
    top:-300px;
    margin-bottom: -300px;
    left:0;
    background-color:#00f;
    width:220px;
    height:300px;
    opacity:0.4;
    color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <div class="tweetty">
      <img src="http://www.picgifs.com/clip-art/cartoons/tweety/clip-art-tweety-191375.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="image-vest">Tweetty-one</div>
  </div>

  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <div class="tweetty">
      <img src="http://www.picgifs.com/clip-art/cartoons/tweety/clip-art-tweety-191375.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="image-vest">Tweetty-two</div>
  </div>

  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <div class="tweetty">
      <img src="http://www.picgifs.com/clip-art/cartoons/tweety/clip-art-tweety-191375.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="image-vest">Tweetty-three</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

(here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uhowp621/6/) version)